# Basic apache httpd.conf to accept PUT GET to any sub url

Tags: docker, apache

So, I have modified the default `httpd.conf` from the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)
and I can't seem to get what I need.

Very simple:
I need `PUT` `GET` on anything under the main htdocs directory, such that the path relative to the host is modeled in the htdocs directory.

So, `curl -X PUT http://localhost/my/deep/path/foo.jq @foo.jq` then `curl  http://localhost/my/deep/path/foo.jq` succeeds. However, my PUT request, as shown, fails:

```bash
curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:11111/foo.jq -d @foo.jq
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:11111...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 11111 (#0)
> PUT /foo.jq HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:11111
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 29
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2023 01:54:49 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.57 (Unix)
< Allow: POST,OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,TRACE
< Content-Length: 220
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for this URL.</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Here is the section in my httpd.conf file I believe is most relevant. This is for prototyping a PoC.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    <LimitExcept GET PUT OPTIONS>
        Allow from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```